# postgres restore reporting spurious primary key issue

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to restore a Postgres database, with the following command:

```
pg_restore --verbose -h localhost -p 5436 -d my_database --format=c --clean --no-owner --no-privileges --no-tablespaces --jobs=1 Sunday2.backup
```

During the restore, I see this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2540; 0 16531 TABLE DATA foo_searchresult uoj9bg6vn4cqm
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "foo_searchresult": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_searchresult_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(63) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY foo_searchresult, line 1
```

I went back to the source database and ran this:

```
select id, count(*)
from foo_searchresult
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

and got nothing.

Now if I just try to restore that one table to a brand-new database:

```
pg_restore --verbose -h localhost -p 5436 -d brand_new_database --format=c --clean --no-owner --no-privileges --no-tablespaces --jobs=1 -t foo_searchresult Sunday2.backup
```

it comes back clean.

UPDATE:  I just tried restoring the ENTIRE backup to a brand-new database, and it seems to have made it past foo_searchresult without issue.

(Incidentally, the source database is 9.4, and the target database is 9.5, but I get the same results using the pg_restore from a 9.4 or 9.5 distribution.)

UPDATE:  So it seems that dropping the database, then creating an empty one and re-loading that (rather than using the --clean flag) resolved a whole multitude of issues

Anyway, my question was "Has anyone seen this before, or have any idea how to fix it."

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `having count(*)  > 1` might give more results